Hidden Date Input Trigger Calendar OnClick
Simple problem but I am not sure if I think it right. I have a project on NextJS and want to make a date input but also have a custom placeholder and the input still be usable.
I have come to a stop, my current setup is that I have my Date Input hidden, and a paragraph displaying the placeholder I want...how do I make an OnClick event or a Ref to make the input usable by the user? Is there a way? Or else what can I do to also have a placeholder and a date input?
TypeScipt:
       <input
            type="date"
            name={label}
            id={label}
            value={date}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setDate(e.currentTarget.value)}
            tabIndex={tabIndex}
            hidden
        />
        <p className={style.calendarFakeInput}>{placeholder}</p>

SCSS:
    .calendarFakeInput {
     color: $grey2;
     width: 100%;
     cursor: default;
    }
    input[type="date"] {
     position: relative;
     color: $grey2;
    }
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     background: transparent;
     bottom: 0;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
     height: auto;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: auto;
    }

On the parent component of these I tried this with no luck...
<div className={style.calendarInput} onClick={() => document.getElementById(`${label}`)?.click()}>


This question is similar to: Not showing placeholder for input type="date" field. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no placeholder attribute support when the type is set to "date". There are workarounds of varying efficacy. See the dupe.

I'm not sure what the rest of the code looks like but we should be able to use native React hooks to handle the state of the input and the onClick. For the placeholder, we can use custom css to create a "placeholder"-like design.
Check out the code snippet below:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Calendar() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<string>('');
  return (
    <input
      type='date'
      placeholder='Enter a date'
      value={date}
      onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        setDate(e.currentTarget.value)
      }
    />
  );
}

with added CSS of
input[type='date']:not(.has-value):before {
  color: lightgray;
  content: attr(placeholder);
}


Thank you for your advice. The trick with the placeholder somewhat works. For me it just makes the input taller and the placeholder appears above the default MM/DD/YYYY value. To be more specific I would like the placeholder to act like a placeholder on a type text field. I don't want this MM/DD/YYYY appear. As for the state I already figured it out, I understand that part pretty clearly. I would like to know if there is a way to "trigger" the type date input via JSX. Thank you again!
